# Unable to boot from cd or live usb on Toshiba satellite U945-S4140

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, uefi

I am trying to completely switch over to ubuntu from a my toshiba ultrabook. Link to product page: http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/U940/U945-S4110
I previously had linux mint dual booted with windows 8, and to get that to work my friend had to do something to the computer. I have the iso for ubuntu 14.04 LTE loaded onto a cd, and I have tried starting my computer with my external usb disk drive, but I keep getting the message "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected boot device and press a key" even though I have the UEFI set up to boot from my cd drive. I was able to previously install ubuntu, but right at the end of the install the bootloader failed to install correctly. How should I proceed to be able to join the ubuntu family?

Comment: The Ubuntu 14.04 iso is too large to fit on a CD, so you have to put it on either a DVD or a USB flash drive >=2GB. The official instructions for doing this from ubuntu.com are: [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) and [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Answer (score -1):

In order to install from a USB device you may need to include a USB installer on the media. Doing so will allow your computer to recognize the media as bootable. You may be able to use the same process used to make a bootable pendrive. Try going to www.Ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. I did this process with a 2 GB pen drive and got a successful install. However, I also had to ensure my computer was set to recognize the drive as an external hard drive and set it to top priority in the boot sequence.

Comment: You have a BIOS boot.  This guy has UEFI boot and these are otally different systems on how to boot.  To reverse the negative reputation you now have, please [edit] your answer and completely revamp it for UEFI boot or delete it altogether to get your points back.